# how to scrape <td> contents of another we site using web scraping

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, web-scraping

I'm getting this below value while scraping , i just need only 28 from this string

```
<td colspan="2" class="invalid">
  28 Errors, 3 warning(s)


</td>
```

my code

```
string strurl = "http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=" + url + "";
StreamReader stream = objm.URLServerRequest(strurl)
 string myResponse = stream.ReadToEnd();
MatchCollection AltTag = Regex.Matches(myResponse, @"(?si)<td\b[^<]*?>(.*?)</td>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: Change `h3` in the code to `td`.

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: Also, be sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/76337

Comment: i just want inner content only of td , or i want to do substring and extract the errors value i.e 28 . @JohnSaunders

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the contents of `TD` node, you need to use `td` in the regex:

```
var myResponse = "<td class=\"att\">Text</td><td class=\"att\">Text2</td>";
var TdTag = Regex.Matches(myResponse, @"(?si)<td\b[^<]*?>(.*?)</td>");
var results = TdTag.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();
```

This should return all `TD` contents as a string list.

[image]

**EDIT**:

To capture `28` in the new input, you need to use a modified regex:

```
var myResponse = @"<td colspan=""2"" class=""invalid"">
28 Errors, 3 warning(s)


</td>";
var TdTag = Regex.Matches(myResponse, @"(?s)<td[^<]*>\s*(\d+)[^<]*</td>");
var result = TdTag[0].Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output of the [demo program](http://ideone.com/pfxWNE):

```
28
```

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem? Please let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: yes in this morning i tried , its worked for me , but i got 
<td colspan="2" class="invalid">
      28 Errors, 3 warning(s)
  </td>
how to get only 28 from this string data?

Comment: You can use `var myResponse = "<td[^<]*>\s*(\d+)[^<]*</td>";`

Comment: im getting same value i just want inner data of td . not everything with td. or else can u tel me substring method to get my desired error value ?? @stribizhev

Comment: Did you use MY code? The number is inside a capturing group, you need to access it using Groups [1].Value. to get the whole td contents just use var myResponse = "<td[^<]*>([^<]*)</td>"; But you need to use  Groups[1].Value

Comment: As an alternative, use `var myResponse = "(?<=<td[^<]*>)[^<]*(?=</td>)";` it will work with Match.Value

Comment: I have added a demo to show how you can capture a number inside a `<td>` tag text.